# JSoup - Get tag based on text

Tags: java, jsoup

Suppose I have 3 text boxes on a page defined as below.

```
<input id="input" type="search" autocomplete="off" role="combobox" placeholder="Search">

<input id="input" type="open" autocomplete="off" role="combobox" placeholder="Open">

<input id="input" type="close" autocomplete="off" role="combobox" placeholder="Close">
```

I will pass the value 'Open' as a parameter to JSoup and JSoup should return me the data as below (which are the details of the middle textbox).

```
<input id="input" type="open" autocomplete="off" role="combobox" placeholder="Open">
```

Can JSoup do this?

Thank You

-Anoop

Answer (score 0):

You need to select tag by attribute:

```
document.select("input[placeholder=Open]")
```

UPD:
To select tag has any attribute with value "Open" you need to iterate over all attribute values:

```
List<Element> result = document.select("input").stream()
            .filter(input -> hasAttrValue(input, "Open"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

hasAttrValue method:

```
private boolean hasAttrValue(Element element, String targetValue) {
    for (Attribute attribute : element.attributes()) {
        if (targetValue.equals(attribute.getValue())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank You Egor. Is there a way to check in all attributes and not just in placeholder ?

Comment: Do you want to select tag where any attribute has value  "open"?

Comment: Correct. That is what I want.

Comment: I added this case to my anwer